# Can I expand one window over two virtual desktops on KDE?

Tags: kde, window-management, virtual-desktop

My laptop's resolution is low, and some programs cannot display their content normally in a small window. Is possible to expand one window over two or multiple virtual desktops?

Comment: I don't for KDE, but with most window managers, `ALT`+left click anywhere on the window should allow you to drag it around, even if the top bar is offscreen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an unwieldy feature to switch on and off (you have to restart X to do it), but you may be interested in setting up a so-called "virtual viewport". This creates a virtual display area larger than your physical display which automatically (and slightly annoyingly >.>) pans itself around when you move the mouse toward the edges/corners of the screen. It can be distracting, but it'd certainly let you open windows of any size you like - and you might even get used to the constant panning (!) :P

Once you've setup an `xorg.conf` file as per your distribution's instructions (newer Linux distributions do not ship with one, leaving X to figure itself out, which it can typically do now), locate the `Display` `SubSection` and add a `Virtual` line in with the resolution you want, eg

```
    SubSection "Display"
    ...
        Virtual 1280 1024
    ...
    EndSubSection
```

to the requisite part of your `xorg.conf`. Restart X, and your screen should be "virtually" bigger :P
To turn it off... you comment out the "`Virtual ...`" line so it reads "`#Virtual ...`", then restart X. Like I said, unwieldy to switch on/off.

Examine the `xorg.conf` manpage (yes, there's one with that name) for further low-level reading or google "x11 virtual viewport" for somewhat less terse information :P
Probably the two most salient/relevant bits of info from that manpage are the `ViewPort` parameter, which specifies the starting pan-point of the screen (the default is to center the virtual screen into your physical display), and that the first parameter to `Virtual` must be a multiple of 8 or 16 - if you specify a non-multiple you'll most likely discover X has rounded it up or down for you - so it fits the graphics card's requirements.